# How to add a new line in a text file?

Tags: c

I have a few lines of code:

```
strcat(myTxt,"data");
strcat(myTxt,"\n");
strcat(myTxt,"data1");
```

In between the lines I've done `strcat` of `"\n"`; however, when I do a write to a text file the `"\n"` is ignored and all the strings are concatenated as `datadata1`. How can I work around this issue?

Comment: How are you determining that the newline isn't there?  Printing it out?  Looking at it in the debugger?

Comment: why aren't you using fprintf?

Comment: Can you show us a small complete program that illustrates the problem?  The code you've shown us looks ok; the problem is probably in the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: If efficieny matters for you, I highly recommend you to read article [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm)

Comment: Make sure you end the last line with a newline too.  You're writing a text file and need to make sure each line has an ending.  (If you don't, you are venturing out of standard behaviour into either implementation defined or undefined behaviour.)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

For file output, you should do strcat of `"\r\n"`

Comment: No.  For a text stream, the `'\n'` character is automatically translated to the system's end-of-line representation.

Comment: @Keith: All I know is that there have been plenty of times when I've tried using `'\n'` and it hasn't worked until I added `'\r'`

Comment: If you're writing to a *text* stream, the `\r` shouldn't be necessary.  Do you have a specific example where the `\r` was necessary?  (Note that adding `\r` could cause serious problems on a non-Windows system.)

Comment: @ken: That shouldn't have fixed the problem.  I strongly suspect something else is going on.  If you'll post a small complete program that illustrates the original problem, we can figure out what's really happening.

Comment: @keith: For example `FILE *f = fopen("test.txt"); fprintf(f, "hello\nworld");` prints helloworld or sometimes with the little square character in the middle. Replacing `\n` with `\r\n` works.

Comment: @Daniel: fopen() takes two arguments.  What did you pass as the second argument?  (If you called it with one argument and the compiler didn't complain, it's probably because you forgot the required `#include <stdio.h>`.)

Comment: @keith: You're right. I just forgot to include it here.  I usually call it with `"a"`, but sometimes with `"w"`

Comment: @Daniel: This: `FILE *f = fopen("test.txt", "w"); fprintf(f, "hello\nworld\n"); fclose(f);` should *definitely* print 2 valid lines of text to `test.txt` (unless one of the calls fails).  Note that I've added a `\n` at the very end.  If that doesn't work for you, then something weird is going on.

Comment: This suggest amount to pandering to a broken development environment and *will not be portable*.

Comment: @keith: When I put just those three lines in the main method of a C program and run it, it does not include the line breaks. I tried compiling both within Visual Studio and also using gcc.

Comment: @Daniel: Then something is wrong with your environment.  (Possibly the same thing is wrong with the OP's environment as well.)  I don't know what it might be.  I just tried it in VS2010, and it worked; the lines in `test.txt` were properly terminated with Windows-style CR-LF pairs.  I encourage you to post a new question; perhaps someone can figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 6):

This code works for me:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char myTxt[100];

    myTxt[0] = 0;
    strcat(myTxt, "data");
    strcat(myTxt, "\n");
    strcat(myTxt, "data1");

    printf("%s\n", myTxt);
    return 0;
}
```

Did you initialize the buffer's first byte?
Edit: works also with a file as output:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char myTxt[100];
    FILE *out = fopen("out.txt", "wt");

    myTxt[0] = 0;
    strcat(myTxt, "data");
    strcat(myTxt, "\n");
    strcat(myTxt, "data1");

    fprintf(out, "%s\n", myTxt);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 For initializing the first byte; although that wouldn't explain newline characters being parsed out of the string.

Comment: @Daniel, I agree: it's not an explanation.